# GTK+:How to communicating between GtkWindow?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to communicate between two TOPLEVEL GtkWindow.
  For example,I double-clicked the row in the GtkTreeView,and the new GtkWindow is used to modify the context of the row.
  However,I failed to find out a solution except declaring a global variable to pass the structure.Whether I can get a ingenious way to help me solve the problem?
  As a green hand of GTK,I will appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the data through 'row-activated" signal:

```
this_window = gtk_window_new (mode);
that_window = gtk_window_new (mode);
tv = gtk_tree_view_new ();

g_object_connect (tv, "row_activated", 
                  G_CALLBACK (on_row_activate), that_window); 



    static mode my_func_using_data (view, that_window)
{
    // do something here to pass a data to view
    ....
    ....
    selection = view.get_selection ()
    GtkTreeModel *model;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
        if ( gtk_tree_selection_get_selected (selection))
    {
        // modify the data here with model and iter
    }

}
    static void on_row_activate (GtkTreeView *view, 
                                 GtkTreePath *path, 
                                 GtkTreeViewColumn *col,
                                 gpointer that_window)
{
    my_func_using_data (view, that_window)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!I guess if I want to update the display of the tree view in this window after I complete the edition in the that window,I can pass the pointer of treeview in this window through the'row-activated' signal.And after I click the OK btton in that window,I will use the pointer of treeview to update,Right?I believe you give me a inspiration to think that.Thank you for your very detailed help!!